# Copy to clipboard option on slack

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

In slack is there any workflow/app that allows users to post messages with copy to clipboard option as part of their message ?

Ex: I wanted to share a some text (message) with someone which I want them to copy.
(like this one on github):

[image]